# Do the results of debugging tell us anything more than the variables and their values?

Tags: android, debugging, eclipse-adt

As you can see in this screenshot of a debug perspective Variables section (on the top right side), the column named "`Name`" gives a list of the names of variables which have been created so far, and the column named "`Value`" gives a list of the types against their respective objects (`SoapObject`,  `String[4]` - I'm guessing it means an String-type array of 4 values, `SoapSerializationEnvelope`, `HttpTransportSE`), and the actual value of one object `e` (which is `null`) most probably.

1. There are **id's** given in parenthesis as well. Are they the **resource Id's** of the objects (supposedly in gen/R file)?
2. The **values of variables** enable us to evaluate if the variable is of the correct datatype, giving a better insight into **whether whatever is happening in our code is as expected** , right? Do they help us in any other way?
3. Apart from this information, does debugging help us in any other way.

Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.
I saw a few articles about debugging Android applications and they were about how-to's of debugging and not about how to use it. If you know some reading material which can answer my questions, please feel free to point me towards it.

[image: Result of debugging my program]

Answer (score 1):

Objects are not stored in R file, they are stored in the heap. So `id`s are just markers calculated somehow by Eclipse debugger to make you understand more easily, whether some object references point to the same object.